# Mariadb slow_query_log keeps disabling

Tags: mysql, mariadb, performance, mariadb-10.1, slow-log

I'm trying to enable `slow_query_log` on a Mariadb 10.1.32 server.

When `slow_query_log` is enabled & flushed, logging is successful (slow queries are recorded and written to the file) for a minute or less, before becoming disabled again. By disabled I mean the `slow_query_log` variable has been set to `OFF`.

I can't find any indication in logs (`mysql/syslogs`) as to what might be disabling the `slow_query_log`.

Any clues appreciated.

#### options

```
| log_output          | FILE                                 |
| slow_query_log_file | /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow_test.log |
```

Note `slow_query_log_file` per my configs is set to `/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log`; and I had changed to this new 'test' file as part of debugging. I see the same behaviour regardless of file.

We're running the database locally; Debian Jessie.

```
root@xxxxx:/var/log/mysql# ls -l /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow_test.log

-rw-rw---- 1 mysql adm 449 May 25 09:40 /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow_test.log
```

These configs are set in `my.cnf` since the last restart:

```
root@xxxx:/var/log/mysql# cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/mygalera.cnf | grep slow
slow_query_log              = 1
slow_query_log_file         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
```

Long query time:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@global.long_query_time\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@global.long_query_time: 10.000000
```

I pointed the file back to the default (`/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log`), flush & enable, it logged again until 11:50:

```
 - -rw-r-----  1 mysql adm   861 May 25 11:47 mariadb-slow.log
 - -rw-r-----  1 mysql adm  2.1K May 25 11:50 mariadb-slow.log
```

This makes me think there is something scheduled that is disabling it, however `event_scheduler` is off and nothing in `cron`.

Comment: Questions : 1) Did you set these options in my.cnf ??? 2) Did you restart mysqld ??? What is the output of `SELECT @@global.long_query_time` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. It turned out to be [ClusterControl](https://severalnines.com/product/clustercontrol).

Despite having Performance Schema enabled & configured, ClusterControl's query monitor was starting & stopping slow_query_log as described [here](https://severalnines.com/blog/how-use-clustercontrol-query-monitor-mysql-mariadb-and-percona-server).

Disabling the Query Monitor in cluster control, and enabling slow_query_log resolved the issue.